# PaginatedList onpostasync - ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'model') when submitting on paginnatelist

Tags: html, asp.net-core, pagination, razor-pages, .net-5

HI Perhaps someone can point me in the right direction.

I created a paginated list page use the example on the ms site.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-5.0

and modified it slightly. I replaced one item with a input box as would like to edit the list and do a bulk save instead on opening every item on a new page to edit it.
but when it click the submit button i get the error.

ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'model')
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.PageModel.TryValidateModel(object model, string name)

if I bind the property

```
 [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public PaginatedList<CompanyDataListing> CustomersDisplayList { get; set; }
```

i get the follow error

ArgumentException: Type 'BizFinder.PaginatedList`1[BizFinder.Data.CompanyDataListing]' does not have a default constructor (Parameter 'type')

and even the paginated list does not render.

My code for the sumbit is as follows.

```
        public PaginatedList<CompanyDataListing> CustomersDisplayList { get; set; } 

     public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!TryValidateModel(CustomersDisplayList, nameof(CustomersDisplayList)))
            {
                return Page();
            }
                foreach (var item in CustomersDisplayList)
            {
                if (item.GoogleCategory != "")
                {
                    string cat = item.GoogleCategory;
                }

            }  


            return Page();
        }
```

and my html is as follow.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post,
new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                  <a asp-page="./Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@Model.NameSort"
                   asp-route-currentFilter="@Model.CurrentFilter">
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CustomersDisplayList[0].CompanyName)
                </a>
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CustomersDisplayList[0].Keywords)
            </th>
            <th>
                 <a asp-page="./Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@Model.DateSort"
                   asp-route-currentFilter="@Model.CurrentFilter">
                   @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CustomersDisplayList[0].GoogleCategory)
                </a>
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.CustomersDisplayList)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                     <input type="hidden" asp-for="CustomersDisplayList[0].Id" />
       
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CompanyName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Keywords)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @*@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GoogleCategory)*@

                        <input asp-for="CustomersDisplayList[0].GoogleCategory"  name="Category1"   placeholder="Input your keyword" class="form-control GoogleCategory"  autofocus="autofocus" />
                <span asp-validation-for="CustomersDisplayList[0].GoogleCategory" class="text-danger"></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                    <a asp-page="./Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                    <a asp-page="./Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

   <div asp-validation-summary="All">
            <span>Please correct the following errors</span>
        </div>

        @* @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
}
```

and the full code base is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using BizFinder.Data;
using BizFinder.ViewModels;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
//https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-5.0
namespace BizFinder.Pages.Admin
{
    public class ManCatergoryModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;
        private readonly IAuthorizationService _authorizationService;
        public int PageSize { get; set; } = 10;

        // private readonly SchoolContext _context;
        public ManCatergoryModel(ApplicationDbContext context, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _context = context;
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public string NameSort { get; set; }
        public string DateSort { get; set; }
        public string CurrentFilter { get; set; }
        public string CurrentSort { get; set; }

        //   public IList<CompanyDataListing> CustomersDisplayList { get; set; }
   //  [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public PaginatedList<CompanyDataListing> CustomersDisplayList { get; set; } 

        public async Task OnGetAsync(string sortOrder,
            string currentFilter, string searchString, int? pageIndex)
        {
            CurrentSort = sortOrder;
            NameSort = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "CompanyName" : "";
            DateSort = sortOrder == "Keywords" ? "date_desc" : "Date";
            if (searchString != null)
            {
                pageIndex = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                searchString = currentFilter;
            }

            CurrentFilter = searchString;

            // using System;


            IQueryable<CompanyDataListing> CompData = from s in _context.CompanyDataList
                                                      where s.GoogleCategory == null
                                                      select s;

            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "name_desc":
                    CompData = CompData.OrderByDescending(s => s.CompanyName);
                    break;
                case "Date":
                    CompData = CompData.OrderBy(s => s.Keywords);
                    break;
                case "GoogleCategory":
                    CompData = CompData.OrderByDescending(s => s.GoogleCategory);
                    break;
                default:
                    CompData = CompData.OrderBy(s => s.CompanyName);
                    break;
            }

            // var pageSize = Configuration.GetValue("PageSize", 4);
            CustomersDisplayList = await PaginatedList<CompanyDataListing>.CreateAsync(
                CompData.AsNoTracking(), pageIndex ?? 1, PageSize);

        }


        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(PaginatedList<CompanyDataListing> Datalist)
        {


          //  List < CompanyDataListing >  mm = CustomersDisplayList.ToList();

            foreach (var item in Datalist)
            {
                string str = item.GoogleCategory;
            }

            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to know is that the pagination in the tutorial is the back-end pagination. When you click the next page, the data is re-requested every time, so if you want to submit in batches, you can only submit current page data.

If you want the data of the current page to be submitted in batches, then you can modify your code as follows.

PageModel:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly PageListRazorContext _context;
    private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;

    
    public IndexModel(PageListRazorContext context, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _context = context;
        Configuration = configuration;
    }
    public string NameSort { get; set; }
    public string KeywordsSort { get; set; }
    public string CurrentSort { get; set; }
    public PaginatedList<CompanyDataListing> CompanyDataListing { get;set; }

    public async Task OnGetAsync(string sortOrder,int? pageIndex)
    {
        NameSort = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
        KeywordsSort = sortOrder == "Keywords" ? "keywords_desc" : "Keywords";
      
        IQueryable<CompanyDataListing> company = from s in _context.CompanyDataListing
                                                    select s;
        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "name_desc":
                company = company.OrderByDescending(s => s.CompanyName);
                break;
            case "Keywords":
                company = company.OrderBy(s => s.Keywords);
                break;
            case "keywords_desc":
                company = company.OrderByDescending(s => s.Keywords);
                break;
            default:
                company = company.OrderBy(s => s.CompanyName);
                break;
        }
        var pageSize = Configuration.GetValue("PageSize", 4);
      
        CompanyDataListing = await PaginatedList<CompanyDataListing>.CreateAsync(
            company.AsNoTracking(), pageIndex ?? 1, pageSize);
    }
    public IActionResult OnPost(List<CompanyDataListing> Datalist)
    {

        //....

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
}
```

Page:

```
<form method="post">
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <a asp-page="./Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@Model.NameSort">
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CompanyDataListing[0].CompanyName)
                </a>
            </th>
            <th>
                <a asp-page="./Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@Model.KeywordsSort">
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CompanyDataListing[0].Keywords)
                </a>
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CompanyDataListing[0].GoogleCategory)
            </th>

            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.CompanyDataListing)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.CompanyName" name="Datalist[@i].CompanyName" />
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CompanyName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.Keywords" name="Datalist[@i].Keywords" />
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Keywords)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input asp-for="@item.GoogleCategory" name="Datalist[@i].GoogleCategory" placeholder="Input your keyword" class="form-control GoogleCategory" autofocus="autofocus" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="@item.GoogleCategory" class="text-danger"></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Edit</a> |
                    <a asp-page="./Details" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Details</a> |
                    <a asp-page="./Delete" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Delete</a>
                </td>
               @{i++;}
            </tr>
           
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</div>
@{
    var prevDisabled = !Model.CompanyDataListing.HasPreviousPage ? "disabled" : "";
    var nextDisabled = !Model.CompanyDataListing.HasNextPage ? "disabled" : "";
}

<a asp-page="./Index"
   asp-route-sortOrder="@Model.CurrentSort"
   asp-route-pageIndex="@(Model.CompanyDataListing.PageIndex - 1)"
   class="btn btn-primary @prevDisabled">
    Previous
</a>
<a asp-page="./Index"
   asp-route-sortOrder="@Model.CurrentSort"
   asp-route-pageIndex="@(Model.CompanyDataListing.PageIndex + 1)"
   class="btn btn-primary @nextDisabled">
    Next
</a>
</form>
```

Test result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. that worked like a charm, can upvote yet but would if I could. For everyone else the solution was to bind the value of the get to a input box and use that as the get model was not bindable.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing `CustomerDisplayList` in the `OnPost` handler but it has not been initialised, hence the exception. You initialised it in the OnGet handler, but that only executes for GET requests. If you want to use a POST request, you also need to initialise the `CustomerDisplayList` in that too.

For what it's worth, the example you linked to uses GET requests for the whole cycle. This usually makes more sense for things like paginating and filtering results. That way, the criteria are passed in the URL as query string values or route data, which means that you can bookmark filtered/paged results. You won't need to render the anti forgery token for GET requests.